# What do dashes in words mean?

Tags: syntax

Once again, i was reading about the [West Bomberai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bomberai_languages) languages when i saw something like this:

> ni- 
> -rik

It had dashes before and after words. I saw many words like this in the [Proto-Trans New Guinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Trans%E2%80%93New_Guinea_language).
Some words like:

> nVŋg- 
> tVmV- 
> p(e,i)t(e,i)o-

I also saw a word that had a dash before and after the word, like in [Mednyj Aleut](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/CIA-verbal-derivational-suffixes-Meaning-Example-ca-causative-reflexive-oblig_tbl4_260088041), something like:

> -ya- 
> -ni- 
> -x̂ta-

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Normally, that would mean that they’re not words but prefixes, suffixes and infixes, respectively (similar to _anti-_ or _-ness_ in English). No idea if there’s a different convention for Bomberai languages, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about things like -xta-

Comment: Those would then be infixes, which English doesn’t have (except for _expletive infixation_, like ‘bloody’ in _abso-bloody-lutely_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet also depending on your analysis of (traditionally proscribed, but very commonly used) "a whole nother", "whole" might be able to behave as an infix in that particular instance

Comment: They also may be roots and the "-" shows where morphemes can be attached

Comment: Building on Ergative Man's comment, the "-" frequently shows morphemes that require prefixes are suffixes when used in actual utterances.  That requirement prevents you from writing them as stand-alone words.

Comment: Using a dash is a convention to distinguish independent lexical items like _book_ or _open_ from items like _anti-_ and _-dom_, which hafta be attached to words and can't stand alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To put it all together: if a morpheme in its citation form is written with a dash on one side or with dashes on both sides, it means it is a [bound morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_and_free_morphemes), a morpheme that can appear only as part of a larger expression, of a longer sequence of morphemes, but it cannot stand alone. The dash shows the side where other morphemes are attached.

That is why the prefixes are usually cited with a dash on the right (e.g. *un-*), since what follows a prefix is written after it, on the right (e.g. ***un**kind*). Similarly, the suffixes are cited with a dash on the left (e.g. *-ness*), since the rest of the word precedes a suffix and is written on the left of the suffix (e.g. *kind**ness***).

The morpheme with dashes on both sides should have something attached to it on both sides, it can be an empty (meaningless) morpheme, like *-o-* in “speed**o**meter”, in other languages it can also be a bound root or an [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix), a morpheme inserted inside another morpheme.

There can also be morphemes with dashes inside them, like *-e-k-*, the bound verb root “to fall” in the [Archi language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archi_language), a disrupted/discontinuous morpheme which in actual phrase must always have a prefix, an infix inside, and one or more suffixes. And there are [circumfixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumfix), two-part morphemes in which one part is put at the beginning and the other part at the end of the word, they are usually cited as “X-⟩...⟨-Y”, but often as just “X- -Y” like a German past participle circumfix cited as *ge-⟩...⟨-t* or sometimes as *ge- -t*: *machen* “to make”, ***ge**mach**t*** “made”.

The dash shows the place where some other morpheme(s) should be added to produce a valid utterance.